# SocketIOClient doesn't work on Xamarin.Android in Release mode

Tags: android, socket.io, xamarin

I'm using SocketIOClient in Xamarin.Android App and it's well on Debug mode. But when I'm trying to build in Release mode I have exception: `"Exception on InvokeOnEvent: No overload for method 'Emit' takes '4' arguments".` The same code in VS2012 works well. Do anybody have same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, need to reference another lib.

Comment: It is fine to answer your own question, but please provide an answer with enough detail so that future readers will be able to use the answer to help them solve a similar issue.